# How to subscribe to field changes only after the form has been initialized in react-final-form

Tags: reactjs, react-final-form, final-form

I have a `react-final-form` form, which needs to be initialized from the state. When one of the fields changes I want to reset the form to initial (empty) values. So I use subscription to the field's [dirty](https://final-form.org/docs/final-form/types/FieldState#dirty) state and if it changes I use `OnChange` to reset the form:

```
<Field name="option" subscription={{ dirty: true }}>
  {({ input: { onChange } }) => (
    <OnChange name="option">
      {value => {
        form.reset({
          ...initialValues,
          option: value
        });
      }}
    </OnChange>
  )}
</Field>
```

But it doesn't work, as the form gets reset immediately after it has been initialized. Is there any way to separate these two events? So that I could reset the form only if its field has been modified by the user?

Here is the link to my [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/form-reset-w-initial-values-iu8hl?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't work because `<Field />` component will need to be rendered at least first time because its purpose is to rendering field UI not to hook callback. I'd suggest you to use `<FormSpy />` instead because it intend for hooking callback even though it might hard for specific field

```
 <FormSpy
    subscription={{ dirtyFields: true }}
    onChange={props => {
        if (props.dirtyFields.option) {
        form.reset({
            ...initialValues,
            option:
            form.getFieldState("option") &&
            form.getFieldState("option").value
        });
        }
    }}
/>
```

[codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/form-reset-w-initial-values-ep7b8)

[FormSpy](https://final-form.org/docs/react-final-form/api/FormSpy)

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply! I already have one FormSpy component with subscription to values with an onChange function. Can I add another FormSpy component or should I use only one FormSpy for both needs?

Comment: @jupiteror You can add another FormSpy. I suggest you separate it so that <FormSpy /> will not have too many logic (separate of concern). it'll be more maintainable